# Как построить график вероятности используя printf Java

Tags: java, график, printf

По состовленной вероятности нужно построить график используя оси X Y. Начало координат -
левый верхний угол экрана, ось X - это левая граница экрана (направленная
вниз) .Она соответствует суммам номиналов (5-30). Вот Y - верхняя строка
консоли (направленная вдоль строки экранах). Она соответствует вероятности в
нужном масштабе. Для Метки значение на графике использова
символьный Вывод пробелов (или '_') и одного символа '*'.
Начало каждой строки определяет точки на оси X со значениями 05,06, ..., 30.
Масштабировать максимум Функции вероятностей на отметке 100-й позиции
строками.
Про саму задачу на вероятность: В эксперименте выбрасываются 5 игральных кубиков 10000 раз.
Вывести таблицу вероятностей получения сумм номиналов от 5 до 30.
Таблицу сделал, вероятности нашел. Вот как график нарисовать - не могу.
Вот мой код :

````
int sum = 0;
        int[] base = new int[30];

        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                sum += (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);

            base[sum - 1] += 1;
            sum = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 5; i <= 30; i++)
            System.out.printf("%6d", i);

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 4; i < 30; i++)
            System.out.printf("%5.2f%%", (double) base[i] / 10000);

        System.out.println("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 5; j <= 30; j++) {
                
            }
        }

        for (int i = 5; i <= 30; i++)
            System.out.printf("%2d\n", i);
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

#### Вот код:

```
    int sum = 0;
    int[] base = new int[30];

    for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            sum += (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);

        base[sum - 1] += 1;
        sum = 0;
    }
    String[][] text2D = new String[102][27];
    int strW = 4; // Попробуй менять - Ширина ячейки по горизонаталии (в символах) 
    String grafickBorder = "#####"; // Попробуй менять
    String grafick = "#####"; // Попробуй менять - Так же выглядит неплохо с "####" или "****"
    
    text2D[0][0] = "№\\%"; // Правый Верхний угол
    // Рисуем Край с процентами
    for (int x = 1; x < text2D.length; x++) {
        text2D[x][0] = (x-1) + "%";
    }
    // Рисуем Край с числами 5-30
    for (int y = 1; y < text2D[0].length; y++) {
        text2D[0][y] = (y+4) + " ";
    }

    // Созданием графика (Вариант №1)
    /*for (int i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
        System.err.println(base[i]/10000);
        try {
            text2D[base[i]/10000 + 1][i+1] = grafickBorder;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
    }*/

    // Созданием графика (Вариант №2)
    for (int i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
        System.err.println(base[i]/10000);
        try {
            int id = base[i]/10000 + 1;
            for (int j = id; j > 0; j--) {
                text2D[j][i+1] = grafick;
            }
            text2D[id][i+1] = grafickBorder;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
    }
    

    // Печать в консоль
    for (int y = 0; y < text2D[0].length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < text2D.length; x++) {
            String toPrint = text2D[x][y] == null ? " " : text2D[x][y];
            for (int i = toPrint.length(); i < strW; i++)
                toPrint = " " + toPrint;
            System.out.print(toPrint);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

---

## Выводит:

#### Если Созданием графика (Вариант №1):

```
№\%  0%  1%  2%  3%  4%  5%  6%  7%  8%  9% 10% ...
 5 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 6 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 7 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 8 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 9 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
10 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
11 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
12 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
13 #####         
14     #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
15         #####    
...
```

### ✔(Выбран) Если Созданием графика (Вариант №2):

```
№\%  0%  1%  2%  3%  4%  5%  6%  7%  8%  9% 10% ...
 5 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 6 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 7 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 8 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 9 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
10 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
11 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
12 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
13 #####                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
14 ##########                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
15 ###############      
...
```